# coefficients for getting a smooth equation

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, singularity-theory

I'm studying the equation

$$ x_0q_0 + x_1q_1 + x_2q_2 = 0$$

where $q_i$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree two in the variables $x_0,\ldots,x_5$.

I would like to have some simple choices for the coefficients (in $\mathbb{C}$) of the $q_i$ so that (away from zero) the partial derivatives do not vanish simultaneously.

any suggestions? I've tried a few ones but I was trying to make things too simple and ended up with critical points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is one of those slightly frustrating things in algebraic geometry: according to the theory, you expect that a "general" object should have the properties you want, but any example you write down might not be general enough. I don't know a general (!) method for getting around this problem, but I'll say what I can.

First of all, the equation has to involve all the variables --- if it didn't, it would be a cone.

Next, the common zero locus of all these equations (that is, for all possible choices of $q_i$) is the linear subspace $L=\{x_0=x_1=x_2=0\}$. So Bertini's theorem guarantees that a general choice of $q_i$ will give you a variety that is at least smooth away from $L$.

Let's not worry about what exactly "general" means here, and instead focus on the question of whether we can choose the $q_i$ to make our variety smooth along $L$. Taking partial derivatives, that means that we need to include terms in the $q_i$ that don't involve any of $x_0$, $x_1$, and $x_2$.

The simplest thing you could start with, then, would be to take say $q_0=x_3^2$. Since we need to involve all the variables, it's natural to take $q_1=x_4^2$ and $q_2=x_5^2$. However, it's immediately clear this won't work, because if we swap the roles of $x_0,x_1,x_2$ and $x_3,x_4,x_5$ in the previous paragraph, we see our variety will be singular along the linear space $x_3=x_4=x_5=0$. So there needs to be some mixing of the two sets of variables.

The next simplest thing would be to take $q_0=x_0^2+x_3^2$, and likewise $q_1=x_1^2+x_4^2$, $q_2=x_2^2+x_5^2$. Calculating partial derivatives, we get the following:

$$ (3x_0^2+x_3^2, \, 3x_1^2+x_4^2, \, 3x_2^2+x_5^2, \, 2x_0x_3, \, 2x_1x_4, \, 2x_2x_5) $$
and it's clear these can't all vanish at a point of $\mathbf{P}^5$. So this choice of the $q_i$ does what you want.

This was pretty long-winded, but I thought it might help more to explain one way to get to an answer, rather than just writing one down.

Comment: that's great. maybe you can help me with something else. The solutions to f contain the plane $x_0 = x_1 = x_2 = 0$. I would like now to let it very in a one-dimensional family, so that each member contains a plane. I know that if g is another equation containing the same plane then $\lambda f + \mu g = 0$  also contains the same plane. But this is not what I want, I'd like to have a family where the plane varies.

Comment: Dear John, that's a good question. One approach would be the following: fix the $q_i$, and take two triples of linear forms $(l_1,l_2,l_3),(m_1,m_2,m_3)$. Then consider the 1-parameter family $$ \sum_i (\lambda l_i + \mu m_i)q_i =0.$$ Each member of the family contains then contains a plane, namely $ \cap_i (\lambda l_i + \mu m_i = 0)$, but those planes vary. Of course you need to check that you can choose everything to get a family with the properties you want, presumably generically smooth at least. I'll leave those details to you!

Comment: thanks, this might be exactly what I needed.

Comment: Glad I could help!